# C# UWP How to display a string[] in xaml?

Tags: c#, arrays, xaml, uwp

I have a string[] of bus departures that populates from an API. I wonder if there is any way to show this array in xaml?

Im working in MVVM-pattern and my ViewModel looks like this:

```
    private string[] _departures = new string[7];
    public string[] Departures
    {
        get
        {
            return _departures;
        }
        set
        {
            _departures = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

And my MainPage.xaml looks like this:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Departures}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Departures}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

This is how it looks right now:
[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWM7O.jpg)

Comment: Change the `TextBlock` binding as `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>` which will bind to a item of item collection.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it still dosent show my values. Only the path (Project.Folder.Class).

Comment: An ItemsControl does of course work with a string array property. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the DataContext of your view contains an object with the `Departures` property:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public string[] Departures { get; } = new string[] { "Now", "Then", "Later" };
}
```

Then this XAML works:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Departures}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would create an extension method to get a composed string from a string[] object and bind a property that will call this method.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetString(this string[] myStrings)
    {
        return string.Join(", ", myStrings); // Or however you prefer to combine the strings
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Just thought there would be an easy way to display some values from an array.

Comment: If it is more appropiate you could also just implement this method within your viewmodel. By creating an extension method you instantly have it available within your namespace.